# Normal planes and spherical curves

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, curves, frenet-frame

I am interested in the following result:

"If all the normal planes of a curve pass through a particular point, then the curve is contained in a sphere".

My approach:

Let $\alpha: I \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be the curve (assume it is arc length parametrized). Let $P$ be the common point of all the normal planes. It is a well-known fact that, if $\tau(s) \ne 0 \quad \forall s$ and $k'(s) \ne 0 \quad \forall s$, then $\alpha$ lies in a sphere if and only if $\dfrac{\tau(s)}{k(s)} = \left(\dfrac{k'(s)}{\tau(s)k^2(s)}\right)'$.

Consider a point $\alpha(s)$. Since $P$ belongs to the normal plane of $\alpha$ at $\alpha(s)$, then

$$
\alpha(s)-P = x(s)\overrightarrow{n}(s) + y(s)\overrightarrow{b}(s)
$$

Deriving and applying Frenet formulas, we get
$$
0 = -\bigl(1+x(s)k(s)\bigl)\overrightarrow{t} + \bigl(x'(s)-y(s)\tau(s)\bigl)\overrightarrow{n} + \bigl(x(s)\tau(s)+y'(s)\bigl)\overrightarrow{b}
$$

so

$$ \left\{
\begin{array}{l}
1+x(s)k(s) = 0 \\
x'(s) -y(s)\tau(s) = 0\\
x(s)\tau(s) + y'(s) = 0
\end{array} \right.
$$

Playing with these equations and assuming $\tau(s) \ne 0$, I get $\dfrac{\tau(s)}{k(s)} = \left(\dfrac{k'(s)}{\tau(s)k^2(s)}\right)'$ as desired. However, I don't see how I could prove that $\tau(s) \ne 0$ and $k'(s) \ne 0$.

I am aware that, as Shifrin notes suggests, using the fact that $\lVert f(t) \rVert = \text{constant} \iff f \cdot f' = 0$ helps deriving the result without using the characterization of spherical curves in terms of their curvature, torsion and their derivatives. However, I'd like to complete (if possible) the proof I have been working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly cannot prove this from the given hypothesis, as any circle has the given property. But good try using
the general methodology.